# What chemical is used as a developer in UV sensitive film PCB manufacture?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I recently learned of PCB manufacturing using UV sensitive/photosensitive dry film. In many videos they use a solution, made using  powder chemical (sodium carbonate mentioned in some videos) to remove the unwanted area of dry film after exposing it to UV light. I am not asking about ferric chloride for copper clad etching.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.thinktink.com/stack/volumes/volvi/develop.htm) website:

> The films are developed with a 1% (wt.) solution of sodium carbonate (common soda ash) operating at 100°F (38°C) ± 5°F and stripped with a 3 to 5% solution of sodium hydroxide (caustic soda or lye) operating at 130°F (54°C) ± 5°F.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped really.

Answer (score 1):

I've used NaOH or sodium hydroxide to develop PCBs.

Comment: Thanks, Can you link me to any god good resource. Also is it possible to make smd based footprint(thin tracks) in PCB using this method.